# Could something approximating a Star Wars AT-AT be built with today’s technology?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, science-fiction, warfare, medieval

It must be roughly the same size and height as an At-at and walk on legs, but it does not have to have all of the other At-at features. So no laser cannon or similar, but it can have missile launchers and machineguns. It can use gas turbine engines or a small nuclear reactor (if required) for power.

Bonus point: this would be very expensive and vulnerable to missile and artillery fire today. But if it were to appear in a real world medieval setting it would presumably be a fairly effective weapon? Would medieval level technology military forces have any way of stopping them?

At-at details can be found here:https://i.redd.it/xantjcb4m1tz.jpg

Comment: (1) Boston Dynamics [BigDog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigDog) and the [Legged Squad Support System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legged_Squad_Support_System); plenty of videos available on YouTube. (2) They were perfectly able to dig ditches in the Middle Ages. Humans knew how to trap big animals in the Stone Age; we hunted the mammoth, after all. (Bonus: how would this be different from a real historical medieval [war elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_elephant)?) (Supplementary bonus: the machine guns all by themselves would be *"fairly effective"*, no mechanical elephant.)

Comment: How to stop an AT-AT with medieval technology: 1) Find the fuel supply in the enemy's base. 2) Open the nozzles. 3) Light the puddle of fuel on fire. 4) Run away until it runs out of gas.

Comment: @Cadence Lighting the puddle of fuel on fire is so bronze age. Just use your lightsaber, I mean your firey wooden stick.

Comment: @Cadence Or just dig a big pitfall trap or ditch. AT-ATs don't look like they can handle sufficiently uneven terrain that well, given that they don't seem to raise their legs very high.

Comment: Could we build it today? Yes. Would we? No. The engineering would be vastly over complicated (and therefore expensive) and it couldn't do anything we cant do already using current armored fighting vehicles. In a medieval setting? Pitfalls - hidden pits and traps, as someone else pointed out its high center of gravity makes it an accident waiting to happen. Also hit/run tactics. The maintenance hours on something like that would be enormous, so literally wear it out. Lastly, yes it can blow holes in castle/city walls yes, but climbing inside and then fighting in narrow streets? More toppling.

Answer (score 6):

#### Give Airbus, Boeing, or Cat a call.

The atat is an exercise in size and hydraulic power. That's really all you need to achieve parity with what you see in the movies (ignoring any "walk AI" - I'll get into that later).

If only we were able to find some company that can make large metal equipment with powerful hydraulics:

[image]

Airbus and Boeing both should be able to build a large metal thing with powerful hydraulics - plane flaps and landing gear need to exert considerable force comparable with moving a leg this size.

Many large shipbuilders should be able to do a good job too. Cruise ships have powerful rotating engine pods for precision port docking and powerful horizontal stabilisers to stop rolling on high seas - another big metal thing with powerful hydraulics.

#### More of a DIY guy? You could probably build an atat (or better) in your backyard

*Assuming a big backyard, mechanical experience, hydraulic experience, and an unlimited expense account at the local hardware store.*

4 legged walking robots are doable with modern tech; As pointed out in comments; Boston Dynamics has filled youtube up with their research on this guy:

[image]

I dont remember atat being particularly nimble or stable. I reckon I even saw the pilot manually positioning the legs, so technically this ai beast isnt even needed for parity with the original movie. You can build AI-driven table top walkers out of current-tech Lego parts and an arduino. (My high school robotics team in 1999 was able to build a robot to play table top scale soccer.)

It's more a question of size and hydraulics. And yes, you can build something this large at home; people build things approaching this size and detail for Halloween. Eg this two story atat:

[image]

A skilled mechanic with enough room and raw materials should be able to build a functional, full size atat. A generator, a hydralic pump, few actuators, some piping, and $200,000 worth of random metal parts. Done.

#### Could it be defeated in a medieval battle?

Yes. If you copy the original atat it could be defeated by surrounding your castle with gentle hills or by digging a ditch - the centre of gravity is so high and the leg motion is so minimal they'll topple over on any uneven terrain. I'd rather take the CAT dump truck into battle than an atat.

Combine decent walking ai with modern hydraulics and better leg design and the battle will be more in favour of the atat.

Comment: One problem is that a conventional medieval castle location (on top of an isolated hill or ideally a bluff, with long sight-lines in all directions) and an AT-AT proof castle location (in the middle of many kilometers of rolling hills, low to the ground to avoid laser attacks from a distance) are pretty much exact opposites. Your existing forts may not be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

### Look To Logging:

If we're looking at walking machines, try this one on for size. The [John Deere Walking tractor](https://blog.machinefinder.com/3255/john-deere-walking-harvester) is designed to move freely in rough terrain with soil that can't tolerate wheels and tracks. The basic design is a working vehicle, used in real world situations. While the basic engineering of building a big one hasn't been done (largely because it's impractical) the concept works and is in use. You could easily envision the large arm replaced by a flame thrower without significant redesign. A self-loading artillery/rocket launcher/ recoilless rifle would be easy. Missiles could be easily attached. A minigun would be also quite simple and would deal with most of the threats such a vehicle is likely to face (in rough terrain, you'd need to engage infantry and aircraft).

So you'd want to make it lower to the ground, for practical reasons, and with more legs. But a walker tank? Slow compared to a modern main battle tank, but it's not really meant for terrain you can take tanks into. So the next time you're invading rural Canada, arm and armor some oversized walkers and go at it.
[image: Walking tractor]